# Erlang: Prompt until User chooses to Exit

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, erlang

I'm new to Erlang.

My problem though is I can't seem to figure out how to create functions that will continue to prompt a user until they enter some kind of "exit" button.

I made a very simple program below that I thought would exit if the user typed "4", but I thought wrong:

```
reprompt() ->
  {ok, X} = io:fread("Prompt>", "~s"),
  case X of
    4 -> io:format("exit");
    _ -> reprompt()
  end.
```

I've tried other variations, but most of followed the same or similar pattern.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`io:fread/2` returns a list. With the format `"~s"`, it will return a list containing one string. If you want to input a single number into `X`, you can do:

```
{ok, [X]} = io:fread("Prompt>", "~d"),
```

Note that this will crash if the user enters something other than a number. You should use a `case` expression and add clauses for `{ok, [X]}` and `{error, Reason}`.

Comment: Yes, that fixed everything.  Sometimes it's the small things in life. Thank you.